# What to use instead of DO_NOTHING to only delete one field?

Tags: python, sql, django, database, django-models

I want to link two models like this

```
class t_data(models.Model):
    receiver = models.TextField()
    file_desc = models.TextField()
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
```

another model :

```
class transaction_detail(models.Model):
    transaction_id = models.ForeignKey(
        t_data,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        )
    sender=models.TextField()
    receiver = models.TextField()
```

*yes i am using DO_NOTHING and i have read that it is wrong to use it. But it is not working.

now when a user tries to delete his file, The t_data object should be deleted but the transaction_details should not change.There is nothing specific on my view for deleting objects. Yet, simple example would be

```
def delete_request(request,id):
    requested = t_data.objects.get(id=id)
    requested.delete()
return HttpResponseRedirect('/requests')
```

When I try to delete the t_data object it throws an Integrity Error.

Error:

> IntegrityError at /accepted/1
> FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accepted/1
> Django Version: 3.1.7
> Exception Type: IntegrityError
> Exception Value:
> FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
> Exception Location: C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 413, in execute
> Python Executable:  C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
> Python Version: 3.9.1
> Python Path:
> ['C:\Users\ukfle\Documents\pro',
> 'C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip',
> 'C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs',
> 'C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib',
> 'C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39',
> 'C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages',
> 'C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages',
> 'C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32',
> 'C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
> 'C:\Users\ukfle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']
> Server time:    Wed, 19 May 2021 14:05:40 +0000

How to solve it? Or what to use in place of DO_NOTHING? You can also use OneToOneField if you want to solve this problem. Thank you
:)

Comment: What's the error? Add complete error traceback

Comment: @JPG done! Can you help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check options under on_delete argument in [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey). You can use the `SET_NULL` option which sets the data as `NULL` but as described the field should nullable. `DO_NOTHING` is the worst thing you can do because when a deletion occurs the data stays as it is and there becomes an object that does not exist.

Comment: @Utsavkaf I am happy to hear that. Have a nice day.